# A tower of Cartesian Products is Cartesian

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I am trying to figure out the following exercise from Vakil's notes: If the two squares in the following commutative diagram are Cartesian diagrams, then the "outside rectangle" (involving U,V,Y, and Z) is also a Cartesian diagram.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    U @>>> V\\
    @V V V @VV V\\
    W @>>> X \\
    @V V V @VV V\\
    Y @>>> Z
\end{CD}

So we want to show that for any object $R$ such that there exist morphisms $R\rightarrow  Y$ and $R\rightarrow  V$ making the outside square commute, then there exists a unique morphism $R\rightarrow U$.

I know this is probably just some diagram chase with unwinding of definitions, but I'm having trouble sorting through it. Let $\alpha:Y\rightarrow Z$, $\beta:X\rightarrow Z$ and $\beta':V\rightarrow X$ be labels for morphisms given above, and suppose we have an object $R$ with maps $P_{RY}:R\rightarrow Y$ and $P_{RV}:R\rightarrow V$ such that $\alpha\circ P_{RY}=\beta\circ\beta'\circ P_{RY}$.

I am not sure how to proceed. It seems there is some ambiguity in how to choose the map from $W$ to $X$ since it involves both squares. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the lower square is cartesian, you will find first a map from $R$ to $W$. This map gives you a map from $R$ to $U$ using that the upper square is cartesian. So you have the existence of the map. For the uniqueness, two maps from $R$ to $U$ making commutative the triangles of rectangle would give two maps from $R$ to $W$ make commutative the triangles of the lower square, so they would be equal (from $R$ to $W$). So the two maps from $R$ to $U$ would make commutative the upper triangles and would be equal sinthe the upper square is cartesian.

Comment: Thanks. It became clear to me the second before you posted.